# Why "System.arraycopy" uses "Object" instead of "Object[]"?

Tags: java, arrays

Just curious:

Someone knows why the method `System.arraycopy` uses `Object` as type for `src` and `dest`? Would be perfectly possible to use `Object[]` instead?

Why define:

```
arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

instead of

```
arraycopy(Object[] src, int srcPos, Object[] dest, int destPos, int length)
```

?

Comment: As an aside, there is no need to call `System.arraycopy` anymore because recent versions of java have `Arrays.copyOfRange`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Primitive array types like `boolean[]` and `double[]` do not extend `Object[]` but they do extend `Object`

This method allows you to copy any type of array, so the type is Object.

```
int[] a =
int[] b =
System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);
```

Comment: Cool, dosn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO all the arrays should extend or be equivalent to an array type like `Array<T>` where T can be a primitive type. The method would be <T> System.arraycopy(Array<T> a, int aSrc, Array<T> b, int bSrc, int len)` That way you could accediently copy from an `int[]` to an `Integer[]` which might think would work.  But this is unlikely to change.

Comment: @Peter: your proposal wont work as an byte[] array and a int[] array are in memory of different size. Also it conflicts with 32 bit and 64 bit referenc sizes. Keep in mind the method is implemented in C/machine code.

Comment: @Angel, I don't see what you mean. Currently you can try to copy from a byte[] to a int[] but you get a runtime error. I am proposing that the compiler should be able to tell you this.  You can have a 64-bit JVM with 32-bit references with `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` but I don't see how this is relevant.

Comment: Oh, your previous comment was a bit confusing, I thought you wanted to be able to copy from int to byte e.g. As we can't use primitives as generic type arguments we wont get this any time soon. Of course it is relevant whether you have 32 or 64 pointers as the right routine needs to be called to handle the move.

Comment: @Angel, the JVM will only be using 32-bit or 64-bit references, I don't see how you can mix them up.

Comment: Well, as noted above I missunderstood your point. I assumed you wanted to copy longs into bytes and references of objects into longs etc. I only wanted to point out that this makes no sense.

Comment: @Angel, Some of the combinations which are not allowed would be useful esp. since auto-boxing is part of the language now.

Comment: That was my point (or my confusion), the "usefull things" are not easy to implement as we call a "machine code" method (actually its a C function) here, that is made for speed. A Java method could easily use reflection etc. (Note: the called function is actually moving raw memory around and does not really care 'what' it is moving)

Comment: @Angel, You might appreciate a look at Unsafe.copyMemory(). http://j7a.ru/classsun_1_1misc_1_1_unsafe.html#a6d4a20a539a1cfe3b92bf2297759e724

Answer (score 2):

It would be more statically typed if it has a version for `Object[]` and each `p[]` where p is a primitive. Like the numerous overloading methods in `Arrays` class.

The author of `System.arraycopy` either was lazy, or didn't like clutter in API.